# "Hitting two birds with one stone" Can I use "by" instead?

Tags: prepositions, idioms-in-context

I know that the idiom states "hitting two birds with one stone" but I'm just wondering is it grammatically right to say "hitting two birds **by** one stone"?

Comment: No. It is not grammatically correct to say 'hitting two birds by one stone.' Its like the difference between 'I am walking with her' meaning that I am consciously choosing to walk next to/with her, but 'I am walking by her' just means that we are seeing each other in passing, or we are not walking together.

Comment: Note that **to kill two birds with one stone** is the standard expression (not that there's any grammatical reason to avoid **hitting them**). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit+two+birds+with%2Ckill+two+birds+with+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chit%20two%20birds%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckill%20two%20birds%20with%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Because "stone" is a tool, "with + a tool" means using the tool. For example:
"I am writing my paper with a pen."
Not "I am writing my paper by a pen."

Answer (score 0):

The idiom is **hitting two birds with one stone**. If you say it any other way, people will understand it, but they will know you are not using the idiom appropriately. Yes, it is grammatically correct but no native speaker says that.